# Average waiting time in queue for FCFS and Longest-job first priority queue

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I am currently studying about (non)preemptive priority queue, and below are some problems that I am getting stuck on. Hope somebody could give me some help on any of these problems.

1. Customers arrive to a single customer service agent according to a Poisson process with arrival rate $\lambda = 9$ per hour. $80\%$ of customers complete a standard transaction that takes a fixed amount of time, $\frac{1}{12}$ hour. $20\%$ of customers require special handling and take an exponential amount of time with mean $\frac{1}{6}$ hours. Determine the average wait in queue for **standard-transaction** customers when customers are **first-come, first served**.
2. A computer processer handles incoming jobs according to a non-preemptive priority queue discipline. Jobs arrive according to a Poisson process with rate 8 per minute. $80\%$ of jobs take $1/60$ min to process, $10\%$ take $1/12$ min to process, and $10\%$ take 1 minute to process. Determine the average time in queue for each class if the rule applied is **Longest job first**? How about the average time in queue if **first-come, first-served** is applied?

**My thought:** For $(1)$, what caused me a lot of difficulty is the fact that the two service distributions are not both exponential. I know that if both services are exponential, then we only need to compute $L_q = L_{q_1}+L_{q_2} = \lambda (\frac{\lambda_1}{u_1} + \frac{\lambda_2}{u_2})/(1- \frac{\lambda_1}{u_1} + \frac{\lambda_2}{u_2})$. Then dividing this by $\lambda_1$ (is this correct?) to get the result?

For $(2)$, I am completely stuck since I simply don't know the formula for the rule **Longest job first**. For shortest job first, the formula is: Average waiting in queue of class-x customer = $W_q^{x} = \frac{\lambda E[S^2]}{2(1-\sigma_x)^2}$ where $\sigma_x  = \sum_{i=1}^{x} \rho_i$ = total load rate of all jobs less than $x$.

Comment: Do you know the M/G/1 queue formula? That is all that is needed for problem (1).  For problem (2), you will need to use the extended formula for multi-class M/G/1 queues with nonpreemptive priority (in this specific case you have 3 classes of traffic, each class having deterministic service times with class-dependent durations).  [For both problems, you will need to assume that successive job types are chosen in an i.i.d. manner with the given probabilities.]

Comment: @Michael: thank you very much for your help. Could you show me how you would determine the service rate in problem (1) (I don't think we can simply add the two service rates up, can we?) and the formula to find $L_q^{1}$ or $W_q^{1}$, where the exponent $1$ stands for queue of standard-transaction customers. For Problem (2)< the way I solved it is using $W_q^{i} = \frac{\lambda E[S^2]}{2(1-\sigma_i)(1-\sigma_{i-1})}$. Now, $\sigma_3 = \rho_3$ only, because longest job is processed first, $\sigma_2 =\rho_2 +\rho_3$, and $\sigma_1 =\rho_1 +\rho_2+\rho_3$. Is this a correct way to solve $(2)$?

Comment: @Michael: you meant using P-K formula like: $W=\frac{\lambda E(S^2)}{2(1-\rho)}$, where $\rho = \rho_1 + \rho_2 = 7.2/12 + 1.8/6 = 0.9$? But how to find $W_q^{1}$ then?

Comment: For problem 1, Poisson arrivals see time averages (PASTA).  So both types of arrivals see, on average, the same unfinished work in the system when they arrive, and hence have the same average queueing delay (recall this is FCFS).  Just compute $\overline{W}_q$ and it is the same for both type 1 and type 2. You can find the service time distribution by using the law of total probabilty. You are correctly approaching problem 2, but you need to compute the numerator.

Comment: @Michael: thanks for your patience. Based on what you said, for problem 1, all I need is to use P-K formula to compute $W$ where $\rho = 0.9$, then $W_q = W-\frac{1}{u}$, where $u$ is the service rate of the system. Is this correct: $u = 1/(0.8/12+0.2/6)$ (this is by conditional expectation)?

Comment: Basically, $u=1/E(S)$, where $S = $ random service time of the system. And $E(S) = 0.8/12+ 0.2/6=0.1$, so $u=10$. Correct?

Comment: The P-K formula I use is for average delay in the queue buffer (not including service time) and is $$\overline{W}_q = \frac{\overline{R}}{1-\rho} = \frac{\lambda E[X^2]}{2(1-\rho)}$$ where $X$ is a service time random variable and $\rho = \lambda E[X]$.  Then the total system delay is $\overline{W}_q$ plus the average service time. So type 1 and 2 traffic have the same average delay in the queue buffer, but different average service times, so different total average system delays.  Example: Let $\lambda \approx 0$ and note total average delay of type 1, 2, is then just their avg service time.

Comment: @Michael: I think I used a different formula above,at least for my $\rho$. I have never seen $\rho = \lambda E[X]$ before. Hmm...could you kindly show me some reference link to $\overline{W_q}$? But what you described to me is quite clear now, and it helps a lot!! Thank you so much for being patient.

Comment: Chapter 3 here is a good reference for queueing theory (see equations (3.41) and (3.42) for M/G/1): http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/datanets.html

Comment: @Michael: may I ask an additional question? What if we consider FCFS for problem 2 too? How could we solve this while having no queue (so no formula like P-K exists in this case, to the best of my knowledge)?

Comment: @Michael: no more help for me, Prof. Neely? I also made an edit to the original problem to be clearer on what I am asking. Please help if you could.

Comment: Well, it seems your edits are asking the same questions, so I guess my help didn't help so much.  For Problem 2, it has a queue both for priority service and FCFS.

Comment: @Michael: I am so dumb:( So I could use exactly the same equation to compute $\overline{W_q}$ you mentioned above for the FCFS case in Problem 2. Your help did help a lot, just that I am dumb to not read the given info. carefully enough to see the *non-preemptive priority queue* phrase